# How to query this in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, hierarchy

I'm trying to write a query in LINQ and, so far, I'm unable to make it work. If I've managed to ask the most obvious LINQ question in history then I apologize but I really do need some help with this one ...

Here is the gist of what I'm trying to do:

I have a class for a keyword:

```
class Keyword
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I also have a class for a file:

```
class File
{
    public IList<Keyword> Keywords { get; set;}
}
```

Now, assuming I have a method to do a search for files by keyword(s):

```
IEnumerable<File> FindByKeywords(IEnumerable<Keyword> keywords)
{
    // Let's say that Context.Files is a collection of File objects
    //   each of which contains a collection of associated keywords
    //   that may (or may not) match the keywords we get passed as 
    //   a parameter. This is where I need LINQ magic to happen.
    return Context.Files; // How do I select the files by the list of keywords?
}
```

I've seen examples of using Contains on the passed in list of keywords but that only seems to work for instances where the matching property is a scalar. In my case the matching property is another list of keywords.

In other words, this doesn't work:

```
IEnumerable<File> FindByKeywords(IEnumerable<Keyword> keywords)
{
    return Context.Files.Where(x => keywords.Contains(x);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? I really just need to find files that contain one or more keywords that match whatever is in the list of keywords passed in as a parameter. It's probably got an obvious solution but I can't see it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to find all `File` objects, for which any of the elements in `Keywords` are present in the collection of keywords you passed into the method?

Doing anything with the `Keyword` class inside your query is apparently a no-no. As your error suggests, it can only translate primitive types.

```
var names = keywords.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

return Context.Files.Where(x => keywords.Select(y => y.Name).Intersect(names).Any());
```

Comment: When I tried your suggestion I got the following error: "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Keyword'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: Same error when I tried the second example as well.

Comment: I converted the list of keywords passed into the method so that it became a list of strings (the keyword values). From there, I was able to use your idea to perform the query. I used this syntax:  .Where(x => keywordNames.Intersect(x.Keywords.Select(y => y.Name)).Any());       Thank you so much for the assistance. I greatly appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe since you are having trouble wrapping your head around how to do this with Linq, you should start with something you can do. Some simple loops for example. Once you have that working, you can move on to Linq queries.

```
IEnumerable<File> FindByKeywords(IEnumerable<Keyword> keywords)
{
    var foundFiles = new List<File>();

    foreach (File file in Context.Files)
    {
        foreach (string fileWord in file)
        {
            foreach (string keyword in keywords)
            {
                if (fileWord == keyword)
                {
                    foundFiles.Add(file);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return foundFiles;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to find a linq based solution with some help.

Answer (score 0):

I might build an index first, then query the index:

```
IDictionary<string, List<File>> BuildIndex(IEnumerable<File> files)
{
    var index = new Dictionary<string, List<File>>();

    foreach (File file in files)
    {
        foreach (string keyword in file.Keywords.Select(k => k.Name))
        {
            if (!index.ContainsKey(keyword))
                index[keyword] = new List<File>();
            index[keyword].Add(file);
        }
    }

    return index;
}

IEnumerable<File> FindByKeywords(IEnumerable<Keyword> keywords)
{
    var index = BuildIndex(Context.Files);

    return keywords
        .Where(k => index.ContainsKey(k.Name))
        .SelectMany(k => index[k.Name])
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to use Grant Winney's suggestion  and with a little fiddling get it to work.

Comment: Great.  If you are going to perform multiple searches on the same collection of files and the collection gets large, it will be a lot faster to build the index once then to do a full scan on each search.  BTW, if you find answers useful, don't be afraid to upvote them...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you're looking for all the files where any of their keywords is in the collection of keywords.

I'd write it like this:

```
IEnumerable<File> FilesThatContainsAnyKeyword(
        IEnumerable<File> files, // IQueryable<File>?
        IEnumerable<Keyword> keywords)
{
    var keywordSet = new HashSet<string>(keywords.Select(k => k.Name));
    return files.Where(f => 
        f.Keywords.Any(k => keywordSet.Contains(k.Name))
    );
}
```

Then call it:

```
IEnumerable<File> FindByKeywords(IEnumerable<Keyword> keywords)
{
    return FilesThatContainsAnyKeyword(Context.Files, keywords);
}
```

Since your keyword objects cannot be compared for equality directly, you have to compare them by identity (their `Name`).

Comment: Interesting idea Jeff. I was able to do something like this using the linq snippet that Grant Winney provided. It worked after I converted the Keyword objects to strings (in other words, just used the value of the keywords themselves). Thanks for your help.